# nginx redirect a certain url to a different domain

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

How can I rewrite urls such as http://server.name/forum.php?board=2.0 to another domain?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path part of the URL stays the same:

`rewrite ^(.*) http://other.domain$1 permanent;`

That sends a redirect to the browser which in turn requests from the other server.

If you do not want to send redirects to the browser then you'll have to let nginx talk to the other server. In that case read up on [its proxy module](http://www.nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).